# Writing EPC memory in UHF Gen2v2 tags with Zebra RZ600

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I have A zebra RZ600 printer and I'm having trouble writing the EPC memory of the new DogBone inlay with the monza 4D chip.

My problem is that impinj has changed the bit function to comply with the Gen2V2 specification as described [here](https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/205798798-Monza-4-UMI-Bit-Compatibility-Issues-Field-Note).

I've tried to use Bartender 10.1V and Zebradesiner pro V2.5, both are latest and both don't have a solution for this issue.

Side note, I'm printing tags for sporting events so usually I'm writing incrementing hex values to the EPC and print the decimal value on the tag.

Thanks,
Idan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i solved it:

1. print to file the zpl code of the printing job.
2. change the ^FD1000^FS to ^FD1400^FS (1400 is for 8 bytes EPC or 3000 to 3400 for 24 bytes. it depends on the size of the new EPC data length).
3. write a script to change the printing detail and the data to write and duplicate it to X number of tags (crate one big file with a zpl code for each tag)
4. send the file to the printer manualy with bartender